# Logical operators in the workflow designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Sorry for asking a non programming question, but I just can't figure out how to use the Workflow Designer in SPD2010.

I want to just write the simple statement in the workflow designer:

```
if field equals 'A' OR field equals 'B'
    ...
```

Problem is that I can't figure out how to get the OR (or AND) included.

Do I have to use VS to achive this??? What have I missed?

Regards

Lars

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've not worked with SPD 2010, but if it's anything like SPD 2007, the Conditions of the workflow step should allow you to do an OR, but you have to add two separate Conditions to do it.

1. Click Conditions dropdown and choose "Compare [list] field"
2. Click **field** and **value** to set those, then
3. Click Conditions dropdown again and choose "Compare [list] field"
4. Click **and** to change it to **or**, then
5. Click **field** and **value** again to set those to your second choice

Comment: Wow, so intuitive

Answer (score 9):

1. After you've added the first condition in the workflow step
2. **highlight** the condition then go to the Condition button on the
   ribbon and insert another **"If..."** condition
3. It will put it on the second line of the IF statement and allow you 
   to **change** the AND to an OR.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate answer!  Jim Bob types faster. :D

Comment: This answer works with SPD2013 (as of the time of writing this).

Comment: Worked perfectly! Its so hidden inside the Designer that you cant even think of that it Exists :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the pipe syntax in between your or if  you have multiple or statements on the same field.

For example

```
Current Item:Urgent equals Yes
```

or

```
Current Item:Urgent equal Not Sure
```

you can clear the lookup and type in manually after the equals.

```
Current Item:Urgen equals Yes||Not Sure
```