# How to determine if all choices in a Choice field are checked?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a task content type which uses a choice field set to display choices using checkboxes. Each time the item is edited, I want to evaluate whether ALL choices in that field have been checked, and if so, complete the workflow.

I'm designing the workflow in SPD, and Visual Studio isn't really an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is compound conditions.

If A and B and C and D and ...

Check out this blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/05/14/create-compact-and-powerful-conditions-in-your-workflows.aspx

And this StackExchange question:

[Logical operators in the workflow designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8192/logical-operators-in-the-workflow-designer)

If there is a variable amount of checkboxes you'll need to create a for each loop:

http://sharepointgypsy.blogspot.com/2011/11/create-for-each-loop-for-workflows.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This didn't work out for me but it did lead me to believe that what I want can't be done without custom code, so I was able to find an alternative approach.