# Sharepoint designer, workflow checkbox

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I'm very new to the SharePoint designer and am trying to create workflows at the moment.
I've created a new employee list, where I've created a choice column called software and within software there are check boxes for various software so the end user can click which software they'd like installed. I'm trying to create a workflow which in this case will create a case if a box is clicked for example for CRM. I'm stuck on the If statement part.

Can anyone please support?

Answer (score 2):

Use -
**If CurrentItem:FieldName equal yes**

[Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8192/logical-operators-in-the-workflow-designer) for the details.

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
If CurrentItem:FieldName equal CRM
```

More on how to do this

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Workflow-conditions-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-A-quick-reference-guide-d8e33ac7-9336-487f-a60b-388c4ea497ff

Comment: If I type in CRM, I always get the following error message. "Errors in the workflow prevent it from functioning correctly."

Comment: Since its a choice column, after you select CurrentItem:FieldName the value will be a clickable item..that will bring all the choice values. Not sure what you mean by type in

Comment: Thanks for your support Amal. It is a choice value but it's not a dropdown menu its a checkbox list. Don't seem to have an option to select CRM because the checkbox list is not shown.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this? I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up your workflow in edit mode, and place focus on the stage.

[image]

2. Select condition from the ribbon control

[image]

3. If CurrentItem:FieldName equal yes

For more details:

- [Workflow conditions in SharePoint Designer 2010: A quick reference guide](http://Workflow%20conditions%20in%20SharePoint%20Designer%202010:%20A%20quick%20reference%20guide)
- [Workflow conditions quick reference (SharePoint 2010 Workflow platform)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822976.aspx)