# How can I insert/update multiple line items in SharePoint list using InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am an newbie in SharePoint and part of finance team. I have been tasked with creating a SP site which has the following view (example):

```
    countries: 
<checkbox>    India
<checkbox>    china
<checkbox>    Pakistan
<checkbox>    Shri Lanka
```

Record names:
1. ABC
2. XYZ
3. qwerty
4. bla bla

[Submit Button]

Now the requirement is if i select 2 countries then a total of 8 line items should be created (2 countries X 4 records). If I select 4 countries, a total of 16 records should be created in SP list (4 countries X 4 records). How can i achieve this using Infopath and SP list.

I could not find anybody in my function who can guide me on this to reaching out to the Codeproject community for help. I will really be grateful for any help/guidance/pointers towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you promote those fields into SharePoint columns, you can check their status within an SPD Workflow. You can promote these fields by going into InfoPath and selecting File -> Form Options -> Property Promotion.

I'm assuming by your tag that you have SharePoint Designer to use. If not, don't use that tag, since it's a program not "SharePoint Design" in general. In your workflow, You can check for the checkboxes and create list items based on it. [How to create a workflow in SPD.](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/creating-a-workflow-by-using-sharepoint-designer-and-the-sharepoint-wo) Here is a link that will show the basics on [Logical Operators in SharePoint.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8192/logical-operators-in-the-workflow-designer)

Essentially, create an action to check the promoted checkbox fields, and then use the "create item in this list"  based on how many checkboxes say yes. If you've never used an SPD workflow before, I recommend doing some research on it before you begin. It's easy to use and intuitive, but I'm restricted to only two links so I cant give you more things to look at.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing guidance...i will do some research on workflow in SPD and try the method you suggested. Will post my comments on pass/fail once i try the methods you suggested