# SharePoint Designer 2013 - And/Or priority in if statements

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, conditional

Using SharePoint Designer 2013, I'm actually doing some if statements in a workflow with `or` and `and` in the condition. But I'm confused as what priority is given for these...

Is the `and` joining the condition on both side like if they were in parenthesis? Is there anyway to make sure some part are processed first?

E.g.:

```
If ContentType equals Apple
and Color equals Red
or Color equals Green
    Log to history "Good fruit!"
```

Would that mean that any "Red Apple" or any "Green" fruit would return true?
Because I'm trying to get the `or`s together.

Only way I can see to make it work right now is that:

```
If ContentType equals Apple
    If Color equals Red
    or Color equals Green
        Log to history "Good fruit!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
If ContentType equals Apple and Color equals Red 
   or 
   ContentType equals Apple and Color equals Green
Log to history "Good fruit!"
```

If you have more IF statements, you can use gradually fitering like, you can also use in IF statements logic operators like **|| (OR)** , **&& (AND)** for the values:

- 1.level - `If Color eq Red || Blue || Green`
- 2.level - `If ContentType eq Apple || Orange`

You just write these values into value window :

[image]

[image]

[Or just look here, there are some information too](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8192/logical-operators-in-the-workflow-designer).

Comment: So, from your answer, the `and` has the priority over the `or`, meaning this couldn't work without replicating the `ContentType equals Apple`? Because what I'm trying to achive would be the equivalent of having 5 content types (`or`) and 1 color (`and`), but what if, let's say, we also added `Pear` and `Tomato` as a valid red / green and also added `Yellow` as a valid color? That would give us 9 lines? So we would have 9 statements instead of 2 like this: `If (Pear or Apple or Tomato) and (Red or Green or Yellow)`.

Comment: Yes i think you must do it this ways, cause you cannot use ')' '(' in the code right? If you can use (), so you can define your priorities this way.
If you have complicated IF statement i can try it, where you want to use this statements?

Comment: That is the point of the question. If there is any way to set priority on some part of the statement, but AFAIK, there's no way to add '(' or ')' in SharePoint Designer. Are you aware of any way to do so? Otherwise, I'll have to keep the only way I found in my question (embedded `if`s).

Comment: But where you want to use these IF statements? Yes probably the one i wrote is the only one solution...

Comment: As I told in the question, this is going to be in SharePoint Designer 2013. And I think the best solution so far would rather be the embedded `if` that I posted in my question, as that will avoid having to multiply the statements.

Comment: but what in SPdesigner? you can creeate here workflows, views, and more :D understand? if it in workflow there can be done something else :)

Comment: My bad you're right! Totally forgot to mention it was in a workflow.

Comment: Yes so you need to use statement as i described, or you can use gradually filtering, i edited post.

Comment: Gradually filtering? You mean using embedded if like I did in the question? If so, isn't there any better way?

Comment: editing answer wait minute :)

Comment: edited, look at it and try

Comment: helped you my solution? mark it please

Comment: Sorry for the delay, going to give this a look by next week. But I think you got a very good point with the use of logic operators within the if statement, never saw that before. It looks really promising, I will try this out soon and come back with some feedbacks! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome try them and dont forget check answer :)

Comment: Sorry for the (very long) delay, I unfortunately have no more use for my original question, and couldn't test your solution, but I'll accept it and try to get some time to ensure it works for people that might fall on this question.